# Can't edit CSS Style with double click in chorme Dev tools

Tags: html, css

I'm learning CSS from the news site with chrome,but when I inspect the element with Dev tools,I found it uneditable.

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

And this is the site:

https://www.nytimes.com/2020/12/06/science/space/jupiter-saturn-align-christmas-star.html

It shows in Dev Tools that class `css-mcm29f` is editable,but I can't edit it with <del>double</del> click,is there any trick to achieve this?

Comment: click `element.style {}`

Comment: It works,but I want to know why that "css-mcm29f" class is uneditable

Comment: it's because they're styles being generated by Javascript and set to read-only by the Dev tools. you can't edit them. look at the class name  `.css-mcm29f`  the `mcm29f` appears to be a unique id generated by the library

Comment: Thanks ,and do you know how to set the styles to read-only by Javascript ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to double click. Simply click once on the right side of the following CSS selector.

```
element.style = { // click here only once and add your CSS properties to see the behaviour. 
}
```

Clicking twice again sets it back to default condition.

Comment: Thanks, double click is the wrong operation, but I'd like to know more about the "css-mcm29f" class, why is it uneditable?